# Reactjs Material UI Tabs label will disappear and will retain logo for smaller screen

Tags: reactjs, tabs, navbar, material-ui

So I am new in using Material UI Tabs and I want the labels to disappear when the screen is resized. for example when the screen is in 500px or smaller, the logo will only retain and the label will disappear.

below is the sample code of my material ui Tabs

```
<Tabs onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.status}>
    <Tab icon={<FontIcon className="fa fa-cogs" />} label="Process" value='orderProcessing' />
    <Tab icon={<FontIcon className="fa fa-money" />} label="Paid" value='orderConfirmed' />
    <Tab icon={<FontIcon className="fa fa-industry" />} label="Production" value='onProduction' />
    <Tab icon={<FontIcon className="fa fa-shopping-cart" />} label="Qc and Packaging" value={3} />
    <Tab icon={<FontIcon className="fa fa-cart-arrow-down" />} label="Sold" value='sold' />
    <Tab icon={<FontIcon className="fa fa-ban" />} label="Cancelled" value='cancelled' />
    <Tab icon={<FontIcon className="fa fa-globe" />} label="All Transactions" value='' />
</Tabs>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using this.isDeviceSize(). Here is an example:

**Updated** to show one tab with only a label and the other with only the icon when the screen is small. Previously both tabs removed the icons and the question was actually asking how to remove the labels. Now the example below shows how to do either.

```
import React from 'react'
import {Mixins, Tabs, Tab} from 'material-ui'
const {StylePropable, StyleResizable} = Mixins
import {MapsDirectionsRun} from 'material-ui/lib/svg-icons'

export default React.createClass({

  propTypes: {
    onChangeMuiTheme: React.PropTypes.func,
  },

  contextTypes: {
    muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object,
  },

  mixins: [StylePropable, StyleResizable],

  render() {
    return (
      <Tabs>
        <Tab
          label="Tab 1"
          icon={this.isDeviceSize(StyleResizable.statics.Sizes.MEDIUM) ? (<MapsDirectionsRun />) : null}>
          Tab 1 content
        </Tab>
        <Tab
          label={this.isDeviceSize(StyleResizable.statics.Sizes.MEDIUM) ? "Tab 2" : null}
          icon={<MapsDirectionsRun />}>
          Tab 2 content
        </Tab>
      </Tabs>
    )
  }

})
```